# UIView not Initialized from Storyboard Segue

Tags: uiview, initialization, storyboard, segue

I am attempting to perform a Storyboard segue from a UIbutton that is a day on a calendar to a DayViewController with info on that day. The currentTitle of the sender UIbutton should be passed to a UILabel in the dayView of the DayViewController. It successfully segues to the new VC and assigns the button title to a property therein, however the dayView (and the base view) of my DayViewController is not getting initialized (their addresses in the debugger are both 0x0) and I get a blank page. How can I get these views to initialize in this segue? (I thought views linked to a VC were automatically initialized when segued to?)

Here's the prepareForSegue getting called:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDay"]) {
        DayViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        [vc setCurrentDayNumber:sender.currentTitle];
}
```

Here is setCurrentDayNumber in the new VC

```
-(void)setCurrentDayNumber:(NSString *)currentDayNumber
{
    _currentDayNumber = currentDayNumber;
   [self.dayView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Here is my view that is linked to DayViewController in the storyboard.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DayView *dayView;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this work if you change the @property to `strong` instead of `weak`?

Comment: oh my goodness it does! thank you stranger!

Comment: You are welcome!  Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO), please accept answers (by clicking the checkmark next to the answer) when they answer your questions in order to give credit to the person that helped you!

Comment: thank you again! I was looking for how to give you credit on the comment but now I understand. you have made my first experience with this website a wonderful one I will be sure to start contributing/asking more questions!

Comment: Great!  Try to help out others by answering questions that you have experience with as well. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a property as weak, it will not "hold on" to the value unless someone else has a reference to it as well.  When the new view controller is pushed, the old button goes away, leaving currentDayNumber as the only reference, so it automatically sets itself to nil.  (This is what weak is supposed to do.)

If you want to keep a reference to it no matter what, use `strong` instead of `weak` and make sure to set _currentDayNumber to nil somewhere (like viewDidUnload) so that you don't retain it forever.